# Error Can't resolve this to Queryable Expression

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I have strange error:
My app uses AutoMapper with EF for converting DTO object to EF object.
Automapper mapping is defined for MwbePaymentMethodDtoInOut &MwbePaymentMethod classes
The line:

```
var result = repository.FindBy(x => x.UserData.Id == userId).AsQueryable().Project().To<MwbePaymentMethodDtoInOut>();
```

Gives following error: **Can't resolve this to Queryable Expression**

Comment: Can you post your source/destination types?

Comment: Might want to reference https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1133 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184988/automapper-resolveusing-cause-cant-resolve-this-to-queryable-expression - and documentation: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions